# Do these functions converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the function $$f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 1 - \frac{3}{n} \left(x-1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \frac{x}{n}. $$ For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 1.$ I need to determine whether the convergence is uniformly or not.

I think it is not uniformly convergent. I tried to prove this, but I'm having trouble finding the correct $x$ and the correct estimate. We need to prove that $$\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \geq n_0: |f_n(x) - 1| \geq \epsilon. $$ I let $\epsilon = 1$. Let $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $$ | f_n(x) - 1| = \left| - \frac{3}{n}\left (x-1+\frac 1n\right)^2 + \frac{x}{n} \right|. $$ Now I don't know how to pick $x$ and $n_0$ to get this bigger than $1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pick $x$ so that $3(x-1)^2/n$ is much larger than $x/n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniform convergence is equivalent to $\sup \limits _{x \in \Bbb R} | f_n - 1 | \to 0$. But

$$\begin{align}
\sup \limits _{x \in \Bbb R} | f_n - 1 | &=& \\
\frac 1 n \sup _{x \in \Bbb R} \left| 3\left(x-1  + \frac 1 n\right)^2 - x \right| &=& \\
\frac 1 n \sup _{x \in \Bbb R} \left|3x^2 + \left(-6 + \frac 6 n -1\right)x + 3 \left(-1 + \frac 1 n\right)^2 \right| &=& \\
\frac 1 n \infty &=& \\
\infty ,
\end{align}$$

which shows that, indeed, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thank for the help. I have a question though: is there some theorem that states you have to find the supremum to show some sequence is not uniformly convergent? Just asking, because this is the first time I see this strategy. I always used the definition.

Comment: @Kamil: The formulation of uniform convergence that I use is nothing more than a restatement of the definition that you already know, perfectly equivalent to it but more convenient in practical usage. With time, you will discover that this formulation is the one that gets used in various other more abstract situations, I warmly advise you to get used to it: $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$ if and only if $\sup \limits _{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 0$. The quantity $\sup \limits _{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ will often be denoted $\| f_n - f \| _\infty$ for reasons that are too deep to explain here.

Answer (score 1):

Each $f_n$ is a nonconstant polynomial. Any such polynomial is unbounded. Therefore each $|f_n-1|$ is unbounded, so there is no hope for uniform convergence on $\mathbb R.$